# Is there an specific correct way to split PEX connections?

Tags: pex, hose, split, bibb, garden

I currently have a hose bibb on one corner of my house, and want to install one on each corner.

We have 3/4" pex under the house, and I am wondering if there is a correct way that the connection should be split to go to all 4 locations, or if it doesn't matter.
Crude image explanation below (end points are where the bibbs would be).

[image]

Comment: Usually the less pipe and connections are the best way.  Water flow and pressure will be reduced if more than one bib is on at the same time.  The bottom/purple design probably will reduce the flow/pressure reduction the less amount(just a bit).  This will depend on the original pressure and size of the pipes.

Comment: the 4 port manifold suggestion only works if you are willing to do "home runs" from the manifold to every end.  That means at the first garden hose end you'll have 3 pex lines passing it to reach those other end points.  Maybe less fittings but certainly not necessarily the easiest, but it would provide greatest possible flow at every outlet if all need to be on at the same time.  Otherwise use tees to continue on from each faucet to the next.  There is no "specific correct way" other than not leaking and not tripping over exposed hose or looking like an awful install.

Comment: @ron that was the question, apparently, there is no specific way it should be done, that's all I wanted to know... ty.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to use a [4 port mainfold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003QSOB9E) like this.

3/4 in and 1/2 out to all the hose bibs.

Any of your drawings would work, but the manifold may have the least pressure drop if multiple bibs are opened at the same time.

Comment: Uponor refers to this as 'Logic' plumbing and I have to agree, it's very logical. The manifolds are available in both PEX-A and PEX-B. They reduce the number of fittings compared to using a bunch of tees.

Answer (score 1):

Any of them will get the water there. Some are more efficient than others.

The green one (almost), but remember that PEX is not rigid pipe, so one Tee on the source to a Tee on either side (total, 3 Tees) to the 4 bibbs (2 & 2 not 3 & 1 as the green is sketched) and then curve graciously to get where you are going.

If the source is 3/4, use a 3/4 Tee to a pair of 3/4x1/2x1/2 tees. If the source is 1/2, it's just three 1/2" tees.